# Droid programming with Eclipse in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium

I have a Neatbeans application, that works well and runs well so I want to move it into Android. So I am taking code snippets and moving it into Eclipse, and into a default made droid class. (which compiles, loads, and displays on the virtual device)

The problem, is that a few things that used to "import" into Netbeans, won't in Eclipse, or I am just doing it wrong, not sure.

Usually in Neatbeans I hit "import such and such class" and then it all compiles fine and no red errors appear in the code. In Eclipse, it is not giving any import option to some features, examples are..
DefaultModelList
HTMLUnitDriver/WebDriver (Selenium's program)
JOptionPane

And I am guessing some more will eventually pop up in the future. 
Does Eclipse not support those options or something? Or is it Android that does not support those options?
Can someone tell me how to work around those issues, with their respective problems please?

The program itself is a mobile chat application, that will basically be a mobile version, of a chat that already exists on the web. Pulls chat feed data, lets you post chats back; basically the same thing as the chat on the website, but accessible from your smartphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with NetBeans vs. Eclipse.  It sounds like your app uses the Java UI Framework Swing, from which you have JOptionPane.  Swing is not available under Android, and anything that uses Swing will have to be extensively recoded to use the native Android UI instead.

Your app may use other libraries that aren't available in Android, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does support those options (press `ctrl-shift-o`).  The problem is most likely the transition to Android -- lots of items change names.  The Android native item to use is not `JSpinner` but `Spinner`, etc.

Also:  In Android most GUI work is done with layout `.xml` files, a bit different than plain Java programming.

TLDR:  you're conflating multiple issues.  Eclipse can even import a Netbeans Project directly.

Comment: Well, if Eclipse does not support Selenium, then I can't really do anything else with this particular project then. Right?

Comment: The IDE is agnostic towards which libraries you want to import. Your problem lies in the fact that Android does not support Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Is Eclipse a strong requirement for you? If you love NetBeans and everything is working, why not to continue with it? I believe you can develop for Android in NetBeans too...

http://binarywasteland.com/2011/07/install-netbeans-android-sdk/

Comment: Well, I tried at first but many people said NetBeans is very poor and far behind in the droid developing area. Not to mention I spent like...10 hours trying to get everything setup for android on netbeans with 10+ tutorials, with all of them failing in some manner. So I caved in and moved back to Eclipse.

Comment: In that case I'll second the comments above, that you probably are in a situation where your target runtime (Android SDK) would never have any of those Swing imports. You'll have to think how to port those UI elements into Android. However, if you target runtime is the Java SDK, those package should import OK in Eclipse.

Comment: And doing everything that everyone says I should do, is probably where my limit and knowledge of Java runs out. I'm still new to it so I guess I am at a dead end for this scenario it seems.

Comment: @Austin no not a total ded end.  I am out of time today, but will try to help you again tomorrow.  You should famiiliarize yourself with [Hello World(http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)      and [HelloViews](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)

Comment: @marksimov Hmmm that looks very helpful. One of my biggest issues was making a nice layout that somewhat fit my Neatbeans one, but the UI editor for eclipse is absolute garbage. :S

Comment: @marksimov one of the things I have been trying to find is the equivalent of a JTextArea, this is a chat application, so I just pull the chat feed, organize, and throw it into a textarea for the user to see, but I can't seem to find anything of the sorts for android. Any ideas?

Comment: @marksimov Just to add on to the last comment, here is what I have thus far, as far as the UI goes. You can see that I have this "multitextline" thing where the cursor is in the middle. but would that work for what I am trying to do? Like can it turn into a scrollpane? Here's a url to the printscrn: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/5347/avdimage.png

Comment: @Austin sorry mate, didn't know about these further questions. Hopefully you have sorted it all out by now. If not, I imagine a chat application largely consists of three basic elements: list of messages, input text field and a button. Same usability like with these comments here ^^ :)